# Tkinter : add image as background for all frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having some trouble with a Tkinter App I am creating. I have many classes (creating a complex app) and want to use the same image as background everywhere. I can't figure out how though. I assume it has to come from my parent frame? Anyone can help me out with this one?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
from tkinter import *

LARGE_FONT = ("Courier", 12)

Background = ('#e6eeff')


class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (UserLogin, MainMenu, TestPage, signupPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(UserLogin)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.configure(background='#e6eeff')
        frame.tkraise()

#I have a few more classes after this point (all representing different pages)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = MyApp()
    app.geometry('1280x720')
    app.title('MyApp(alpha 1.0)')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create a base `class ImageFrame(tk.Frame):` or `class ImageCanvas(tk.Canvas)`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create the image once in `MyApp`, and let each frame reference the image via the controller.

```
class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.background_image = tk.PhotoImage("the_image.gif")
        ...

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        background = tk.Label(self, image=controller.background_image)
        background.place(relx=.5, rely=.5)
        ...
```